# propType validation with forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have an component:

```
// MovieSearchResults
const MovieSearchResultList = (props, ref) => {
  //

  return (
    <ResultListBackground
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
      onClick={props.toggle}
    >
      //
  )
}
```

And I pass the prop from a parent component:

```
// MovieSearchComponent

  const clearResults = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setSearchInput('');
      movieSearchResultsVar([]);
    }, 150);
  };

  <MovieSearchResultList toggle={clearResults} ref={elRef}/>
```

Currently it works because I disable ESlint on the function callback.

The issue appears when I add propTypes:

```
// MovieSearchResults

const MovieSearchResultList = ({toggle}, ref) => {
  //
}

export default forwardRef(MovieSearchResultList);

MovieSearchResultList.propTypes = {
  toggle: PropTypes.func,
};
```

> TS2345: Argument of type '{ ({ toggle }: { toggle: any; }, ref: any): Element; propTypes: { toggle: Requireable<(...args: any[]) => any>; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ForwardRefRenderFunction<unknown, { toggle: any; }>'.
> Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible.
> Type '{ toggle: PropTypes.Requireable<(...args: any[]) => any>; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.